# How to install packages (like tweepy, textblob etc.) in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, spyder

I want to use the twitter API. But in order to use that package named tweepy should be installed.

I tried installing it using the command `conda install tweepy` on the Anaconda Command Prompt.

But every time, the installation failed.

Can anyone please tell me how to install a package in Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method works on Windows :

Step 1 : `Click on start`


Step 2 : `Search and Open Anaconda Navigator`


Step 3 : In the Anaconda Navigator, `Go to Evironments`


Step 4 : `There is a drop down menu consisting of options : 1) Installed 2) Not Installed 3) Upgradable 4) Selected 5) All`


Step 5 : `Click on "Not Installed"`


Step 6 : `There is a block stating Search Packages, there enter the name of the package you want to install.`


Step 7 : `Mark the name of the package to be installed in the search results, and click Apply`


Installation will start.


Congratulations! You have successfully installed the package.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get tweepy to install using Anaconda.  I'm using the Anaconda distribution on a Mac. I tried `pip install tweepy` and it installed with no error messages.

Comment: but on my windows, i don't know why but on writing pip install tweets it shows invalid syntax.

Comment: @Jorvis This is supposed to go into the windows command line, not in the Python shell.  In a Python shell you get a syntax error of course because that isn't valid Python.

Comment: @BlackJack Oh... That's where I was making the mistake. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @BlackJack Where wil it install, I mean in which directory will it get installed if I use the command `pip install package_name`.

Comment: @Jorvis Depends on the actual `pip` executable and if a virtual environment is active in that console.

Answer (score 0):

You can please try:

```
conda install -c conda-forge tweepy
```

Source: [tweepy](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tweepy)